# iOS project not showing Interface elements built from Interface Builder in my view

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

I am working on a project which includes many UI components on one view(being built in Interface Builder).  I have found that after saving and moving my project directory, the interface which should include all of these elements, is empty(there are no visible UI components in the view).

There are actually 2 projects.  1 is a framework project, the other is the iphone project which i build & run on the device - everything is contained within a folder which i may move frequently as other members in my team work on it.

the view which is not properly showing elements, is an XIB file which can be modified through either the iphone project or framework project.

Why is this happening and how can i troubleshoot this problem further?  I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Many components will not show if they're not been connected to a property, and some will not show if their datasource or delegate is not connected.

Have you wired everything up, making all of your connections?

Comment: all my connections seem to be wired in correctly.  i do notice however that if i open the iphone project BEFORE the framework project and then open the XIB file, the component connections are grayed out

Comment: Objects will show if they aren't connected to anything, whether its the delegate or datasource. Take UITableView, it will appear on the view, just won't show any cells or text.

Comment: @WrightCS It's been a while since I ran into it, but I recall that neither a UIBarButtonItem nor a segmented control will show in the nav bar. There are a couple of other things, too... UIPickerView or the date version, iirc. It's been a long time since I've created things that I've not hooked up, but I definitely remember there being things.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the view hierarchy in the -(void)viewDidLoad ? As Matthew said, if those components are not connected to properties, they won't be shown. And, if they are not add onto proper view, then they won't be shown too.

You can check the view hierarchy of viewController by browsing the property **subViews** of **self.view**.